# Downloading images with webview

Tags: android, image, webview

I m displaying a gallery from a mobile website in webview . How can i download those images from webview ? Are there any extra settings for webview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
`          `@Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
                boolean shouldOverride = false;
                // We only want to handle requests for image files, everything else the webview
                // can handle normally
                if (url.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    shouldOverride = true;
                    Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
                    // Make a new request pointing to the mp3 url
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                    // Use the same file name for the destination
                    File destinationFile = new File (destinationDir, source.getLastPathSegment());
                    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));
                    // Add it to the manager
                    manager.enqueue(request);
                }
                return shouldOverride;
            }``
```

make sure to add permissions for download manager, SD read, SD write!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do it is to parse the html code of the page and get the images url.

Comment: MY purpose is to save those images(which are displayed on webview  from website ) into sd card by downloading .

Answer (score 0):

Just load the URL of the image with the webview.

Comment: MY purpose is to save those images(which are displayed on webview  from website ) into sd card by downloading .

Answer (score 0):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


         if(url.contains("http://m.dudamobile.com/?source=DM_DIRECT") ){

                     DownloadManager dm =    (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Request request = new Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));
                enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
             return true;
         }

         else
              {
                  view.loadUrl(url);
                   return true;
              } 
 }}

 //register your broadcast reciever of Download manager in the activity

 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                Query query = new Query();
                query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                try{
                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                     // ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        String uriString = c
                                .getString(c
                                               .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
                       // view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(url1));
                       /* Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
                        startActivity(i);*/
                    }
                    }
                }catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item not downloadable :( ",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
         DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```

`