# Save images of a website in Webview (Java)

Tags: java, android, webview

Im new to java and I have an app that shows a website (using Webview). The Website will have a lot of images and the user can select some o them and save to Gallery (save to sd)
How can I do that?

(im using google.com as an exemple)

```
 package com.he4dless.knowyourmene;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is dasresent.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.br");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: If it's feasible, I am interested in the answer...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087639/downloading-images-with-webview

Comment: Sorry  Xaver Kapeller, but this code its not working for me